# How can I create a unique primary integer key of fixed length?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I want Django to automatically create a unique key of fixed length. This is what I have so far:

```
card_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This method will create keys starting from a very low number and it is not of fixed length. I want to have it a fixed length of 7 chars/digits and have it be composed of integers (a string with number chars is fine as well) e.g. 1543534. I call this from views.py to create a new entry in the database:

```
BORROWER.objects.create(ssn=Ssn, bname=Name, address=Address, phone=Phone)
```

Notice that card_id is not specified, so I want to have Django auto-create it.

Edit: here is the BORROWER model:

```
class BORROWER(models.Model):
card_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ssn = models.CharField(max_length=11)
bname = models.CharField(max_length=71)
address = models.CharField(max_length=79)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Comment: Are you creating a new model with this primary key or adding this primary key to an existing model?

Comment: It is a new model, the model is called BORROWER, and card_id is one of the fields for it and it is the primary key for it. The 2nd line of code is what I am using in views.py to create a new BORROWER entry in the database.

Comment: Do you want the field to increment (1000000, 1000001, etc) or be random? What is the requirement for this field to be seven chars?

Comment: Either one works, as long as they are all unique. I would like for it to be a fixed length for the card_id since that's how most card numbers are for book libraries. It just does not make sense having for example '12' as the card number for a library card

Comment: Could you use a uuid instead? There is built-in support for it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield